# @NamedQuery changes table/column name to upper case causing exepction

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, jdbc

I have a table in MySql called Course and I have the following in my Course.java class

```
package pckt.book.ch7.jpa;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;


/**
 * The persistent class for the Course database table.
 * 
 */
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name="Course.findAll", query="SELECT c FROM Course c")
public class Course implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    private int credits;

    private String name;

    @Column(name="Teacher_id")
    private int teacher_id;

    public Course() {
    }

    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getCredits() {
        return this.credits;
    }

    public void setCredits(int credits) {
        this.credits = credits;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getTeacher_id() {
        return this.teacher_id;
    }

    public void setTeacher_id(int teacher_id) {
        this.teacher_id = teacher_id;
    }

}
```

I'm the running the query as follows in another class

```
@PersistenceContext
EntityManager entityManager;

public List<Course> getCourseEntities(){
    //Use named query created in Course entitiy
    //using @NamedQuery annotation
    TypedQuery<Course> courseQuery = entityManager.createNamedQuery("Course.findAll",Course.class);
    return courseQuery.getResultList();
}
```

and I get the following error:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002]     (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd):     org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table   'course_management.COURSE' doesn't exist
Error Code: 1146
Call: SELECT ID, CREDITS, NAME, Teacher_id FROM COURSE
Query: ReadAllQuery(name="Course.findAll" referenceClass=Course sql="SELECT ID, CREDITS, NAME, Teacher_id FROM COURSE")
```

From reading the error, it sounds the issue is that the query generated by @NamedQuery is in upper case, therefore the COURSE table is not found.

In my.cnf I have lower_case_table_names=2 but not sure if that should make a difference.

My persistance.xml is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="CourseManagementEJB">
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/CourseManagement</jta-data-source>
        <class>pckt.book.ch7.jpa.Course</class>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

jdbc/CourseManagement is a JNDI resource in GlassFish that points to a connection pool for the course_management database, where Course is a table. I know I can connect to the database successfully because I'm able to ping it.

Questions:

1. Is it expected that queries are converted to upper case?
2. How can I fix this issue?

I did do some research on this but wasn't able to find anything that fits my scenario. Some solutions recommended changing the table names (which I can't do) or changing the DAO classes names, which is not my case either.

Comment: can you post your class Course and persistence.xml?

Comment: @Abdelhak I've added them to the question.

Comment: Depends how your JPA provider allows you to select UPPER, lower or CaseSensitive table names. Maybe it has a persistence property to do that. MySQL allows case sensitive, but have to have quotes around the table name if sensitive

Comment: lower_case_table_names If set to 0, table names are stored as specified and comparisons are case sensitive. If set to 1, table names are stored in lowercase on disk and comparisons are not case sensitive. If set to 2, table names are stored as given but compared in lowercase. This option also applies to database names and table aliases

Comment: @NarendraJaggi perhaps you should specify what is "lower_case_table_names" rather than just assuming he knows what you mean ... some MySQL connection property?, some EclipseLink persistence property?

Comment: @NeilStockton  it is one of the system variable of mysql, which affects the comparison of table name. the table names are case sensitive if the value is 0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use backticks in the `@Table` annotation to make JPA use case sensitive names:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="`Course`")
@NamedQuery(name="Course.findAll", query="SELECT c FROM Course c")
public class Course implements Serializable { ...
```

Obviously, you have to use the real name as used in your database. E.g. if the name is all lower case, use:

```
@Table(name="`course`")
```

Comment: "Course" is not the table name, it's the entity name.

Comment: "Course" is both the table name and entity name.

Comment: @NeilStockton: I knew it couldn't be *that* easy. Egh. I'll never get used to writing JPQL...

Comment: This is exactly what is was.

Answer (score 0):

Read through your exceptions it says :

```
 Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table   'course_management.COURSE' doesn't exist
```

check through your persistence.xml file , the name you used to store the Database.

Make sure you don,t create your tables manually

Comment: I've added this to the question.

Comment: Can you please point me to any documentation that states that? So you are saying I cannot use a database that already exists? That would be a huge and ridiculous limitation .

Comment: What he means is, your metadata for the tables is inconsistent with the tables you created. The easiest way is to get the JPA implementation to create the DDL and then you either apply it, or update the JPA annotations to fix the problems

Comment: Im sorry but I don't understand, where is this metadata and why would it be inconsistent? I cannot change the table names or create a new table so I need this to somehow work with the existing table.

Comment: please try using a Mysql dbms to query your table with the query in your exception :       SELECT ID, CREDITS, NAME, Teacher_id FROM COURSE , and see if it works

Comment: @AgbalayaRasaq I get the exact same error because course_management.COURSE does not exist, but if I query course_management.Course the query works as expected (this is in mysql workbench)

Comment: lower_case_table_names - If set to 0, table names are stored as specified and comparisons are case sensitive. If set to 1, table names are stored in lowercase on disk and comparisons are not case sensitive. If set to 2, table names are stored as given but compared in lowercase.